# To-do list JavaScript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to make to-do list but i'm stuck with local storage. Nothing appears when the page is reloaded. I assume it's about changeStorage() method but i don't fully understand what i'm doing wrong.

```
function addTask() {
    let addTaskButton = document.getElementById('add-task-button')
    let list = document.getElementById('task-list');
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    let taskText = document.createElement('span');
    let delButton = document.createElement('button');
    let btnText = document.createTextNode('Delete task');

    checkbox.addEventListener('change', changeStorage);
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.className = 'checkbox';
    taskText.innerText =  document.getElementById('input-task').value;
    taskText.className = 'task';
    delButton.className = 'delete-btn';
    delButton.onclick = deleteTask;
    addTaskButton.addEventListener('click', changeStorage);

    delButton.appendChild(btnText);
    li.appendChild(checkbox);
    li.appendChild(taskText);
    li.appendChild(delButton);
    list.appendChild(li);

    document.getElementById('input-task').value = '';
}

function changeStorage() {
    let tasks = document.getElementById('ul').innerHTML;
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
}

function deleteTask () {
    this.parentNode.remove();
    changeStorage();
}

document.getElementById('add-task-button').addEventListener('click', addTask);

function loadList() {
    document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks")) || [];
}

window.addEventListener('load', loadList);
```

Comment: You don’t need to store raw HTML in localStorage using JSON.stringify. Check your browser console for errors. Also, it is probably better if you simply store the value of each item in the todo list as an array, instead of dumping raw HTML: it’s inefficient and bloated.

Comment: JSON.parse only works with a JSON string, not a HTML string.

Answer (score 0):

This should change what gets stored in localStorage into a valid JSON string, and then reconstruct LI elements from it when it's loaded.

```
function changeStorage() {
    let tasks = [...document.querySelectorAll("ul li")].map(t => t.innerHTML);
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
}

function loadList() {
    document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks")) || []).map(t => "<li>" + t + "</li>").join("");
}
```